# How to assert inside a RecyclerView in Espresso?

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I am using espresso-contrib to perform actions on a `RecyclerView`, and it works as it should, ex:

```java
//click on first item
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

and I need to perform assertions on it. Something like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
    .perform(
        RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(
            0, check(matches(withText("Test Text")))
        )
    );
```

but, because [RecyclerViewActions](http://android-test-kit.googlecode.com/git-history/e81b6694887f5c73617759d2728a92beba9b8f12/docs/javadocs/espresso/espresso-contrib-2.0-javadoc/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions.html#actionOnItemAtPosition(int,%20android.support.test.espresso.ViewAction)) is, of course, expecting an action, it says wrong 2nd argument type. There's no `RecyclerViewAssertions` on espresso-contrib.

Is there any way to perform assertions on a `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Maybe the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52737309/espresso-check-recyclerview-items-are-ordered-correctly/52828004#52828004) similar SO question could help

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You should check out Danny Roa's solution [Custom RecyclerView Actions](https://github.com/dannyroa/espresso-samples/tree/master/RecyclerView/app/src/androidTest/java/com/dannyroa/espresso_samples/recyclerview)
And use it like this:

```java
onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.recycler_view)
    .atPositionOnView(1, R.id.ofElementYouWantToCheck))
    .check(matches(withText("Test text")));
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me if the item on that position currently doesn't fit the screen.

Comment: Try scrolling to the position first?         onView(withId(R.id.id.recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo(2));

Comment: Still the same. Wouldn't work e.g. for position = 30. The problem is that `RecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)` should be used of `RecyclerView.getChildAt()` as was shown in the answer below.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me if the item is offscreen, I added the findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position) to the RecyclerViewMatcher. If I do this:    
onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.synology_apps_rv).atPositionOnView(7, R.id.not_installed_tv)).check(matches(withText(R.string.notinstalled))); The test fails, but if I do this:         onView(withId(R.id.synology_apps_rv)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(7));onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.synology_apps_rv).atPositionOnView(7, R.id.not_installed_tv)).check(matches(withText(R.string.notinstalled))); the test succeeded

Comment: What if you have more than one recycler view with the same id?

Comment: @DamiaFuentes Then you need to provide extra matchers that identify the RecyclerView you want to target. For example:
`onView(allOf(viewMatcher1, viewMatcher2))...`

Comment: How do I use `isDescendantOfA` with this approach assuming I have multiple RecyclerViews with the same ID in a ViewPager?

Answer (score 142):

Pretty easy. No extra library is needed. Do:

```
    onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
            .check(matches(atPosition(0, withText("Test Text"))));
```

if your ViewHolder uses ViewGroup, wrap `withText()` with a `hasDescendant()` like:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
                .check(matches(atPosition(0, hasDescendant(withText("Test Text")))));
```

with method you may put into your `Utils` class.

```
public static Matcher<View> atPosition(final int position, @NonNull final Matcher<View> itemMatcher) {
    checkNotNull(itemMatcher);
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView.class) {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("has item at position " + position + ": ");
            itemMatcher.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(final RecyclerView view) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = view.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
            if (viewHolder == null) {
                // has no item on such position
                return false;
            }
            return itemMatcher.matches(viewHolder.itemView);
        }
    };
}
```

If your item may be not visible on the screen at first, then scroll to it before:

```
    onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
            .perform(scrollToPosition(87))
            .check(matches(atPosition(87, withText("Test Text"))));
```

Comment: .perform(scrollToPosition(87)) isnt working. test fails

Comment: This solution works, but in case of failure it prints details about `RecyclerView` itself, not about item at position N, so you might have a tough time figuring out what's wrong. For matcher with better diagnostics you can check out [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72105818) or some of the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70008599) [ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64241245)

Comment: Thanks for adding the example with hasDescendant, that's the one which worked for my case :)

Answer (score 33):

Just to enhance riwnodennyk's answer, if your `ViewHolder` is a `ViewGroup` instead of a direct `View` object like `TextView`, then you can add `hasDescendant` matcher to match the `TextView` object in the `ViewGroup`. Example:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
    .check(matches(atPosition(0, hasDescendant(withText("First Element")))));
```

Comment: Perfect, all I was missing was the `hasDescendant`, thank you so much!

Answer (score 11):

I have been struggling on the same issue where I have a recycler view with 6 items and then I have to choose the one at position 5 and the 5th one is not visible on the view.
The above solution also works. Also, I know its a bit late but thought its worth sharing.

I did this with a simple solution as below:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recylcer_view))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem(
         hasDescendant(withText("Text of item you want to scroll to")), 
         click()));
```

`RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem` - 
Performs a `ViewAction` on a view matched by `viewHolderMatcher`.

1. Scroll `RecyclerView` to the view matched by `itemViewMatcher`
2. Perform an action on the matched view

More details can be found at : [RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions.html#actionOnItem(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Candroid.view.View%3E,%20android.support.test.espresso.ViewAction))

Comment: Thank you! This works fine for a `RecyclerView` with *simple* item views. I have a project with **multiple levels of nesting in the view hierarchy**. If I use your solution there I end up with: `PerformException: Error performing 'performing ViewAction: single click on item matching: holder with view: has descendant: with text: is "Test display name"' on view 'with id: com.example.com:id/my_recycler_view'.`

Answer (score 10):

For Kotlin users:
I know I am very late, and I am bemused why people are having to customize RecycleView Actions. I have been meaning to achieve exactly the same desired outcome: here is my solution, hope it works and helps newcomers. Also be easy on me, as I might get blocked.

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
.perform(actionOnItemAtPosition<ViewHolder>(46, scrollTo()))
.check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("TextToMatch"))))
```

//Edited 18/12/21: After investigating Bjorn's comment, please see a better approach below:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView))
.perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition<ViewHolder>(12))
.check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("TexttoMatch"))))
```

Comment: Elegant solution - works on espresso 3.3.0

Comment: Sorry, but this will not check on the exact position with the given index, but on the whole RecyclerView instead. Just test it with 47 or 45 instead, the test will pass just the same.

Comment: @BjörnKechel - I have reviewed your analysis and agree with it. I have re-edited the approach and checked it. Can you also confirm the new approach checks the exact position?

Comment: The edited approach has the same issue. It does not check the exact position.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, it was necessary to merge Danny Roa's and riwnodennyk's solution:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recyclerview))
.perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(80))
.check(matches(atPositionOnView(80, withText("Test Test"), R.id.targetview)));
```

and the method :

```
public static Matcher<View> atPositionOnView(final int position, final Matcher<View> itemMatcher,
        final int targetViewId) {

    return new BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView.class) {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("has view id " + itemMatcher + " at position " + position);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
            View targetView = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(targetViewId);
            return itemMatcher.matches(targetView);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. It tries to check the "Test Test" text on a RecyclerView instance, not the target view.

Comment: can you share Matcher import package

Comment: `import org.hamcrest.Matcher` (from `hamcrest-core-1.3`)

Comment: It's not clear to me how I should get the `targetViewId` in order to pass it as a param to `atPositionOnView`

Comment: Basically I don't know the id of the item beforehand because each time I run the test it could be different. It could be a TextView, a Button or something else.

Answer (score 4):

I combined a few answers above into a reusable method for testing other recycler views as the project grows. Leaving the code here in the event it helps anyone else out...

Declare a function that may be called on a RecyclerView Resource ID:

```
fun Int.shouldHaveTextAtPosition(text:String, position: Int) {
    onView(withId(this))
        .perform(scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(position))
        .check(matches(atPosition(position, hasDescendant(withText(text)))))
}
```

Then call it on your recycler view to check the text displayed of multiple adapter items in the list at a given position by doing:

```
with(R.id.recycler_view_id) {
    shouldHaveTextAtPosition("Some Text at position 0", 0)
    shouldHaveTextAtPosition("Some Text at position 1", 1)
    shouldHaveTextAtPosition("Some Text at position 2", 2)
    shouldHaveTextAtPosition("Some Text at position 3", 3)
}
```

Comment: Been a while, not sure what dependency versions are required for this code to run, if I get some spare time I will try to go back and find them.

Answer (score 3):

Danny Roa's solution is awesome, but it didn't work for the off-screen items I had just scrolled to. The fix is replacing this:

```
View targetView = recyclerView.getChildAt(this.position)
                              .findViewById(this.viewId);
```

with this:

```
View targetView = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(this.position)
                              .itemView.findViewById(this.viewId);
```

... in the [`TestUtils` class](https://github.com/dannyroa/espresso-samples/blob/master/RecyclerView/app/src/androidTest/java/com/dannyroa/espresso_samples/recyclerview/TestUtils.java).

Answer (score 2):

This thread is pretty old but I recently extended the RecyclerViewAction support to be usable for assertions as well. This allows you to test off-screen elements without specifying a position while still using view matchers.

Check out this article > [Better Android RecyclerView Testing](https://medium.com/koala-tea-assurance/better-android-recyclerview-testing-a5e3ed7ef38b)!

Answer (score 2):

The solutions above are great, I'm contributing one more in Kotlin.

Espresso needs to scroll to the position and then check it.  To scroll to the position, I'm using [`RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions?hl=en#scrollToPosition(int)).  Then use  [findViewHolderForAdapterPosition](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#findviewholderforadapterposition) to perform the check.  Instead of calling `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition` directly, I am using a nicer convenience function [`childOfViewAtPositionWithMatcher`](https://github.com/xabaras/recyclerview-child-actions).

In the example code below, Espresso scrolls to row 43 of the `RecyclerView` and the checks that the row's `ViewHolder` has two TextViews and that those TextViews contain the text "hello text 1 at line 43" and "hello text 2 at line 43" respectively:

```
import androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions
import it.xabaras.android.espresso.recyclerviewchildactions.RecyclerViewChildActions.Companion.childOfViewAtPositionWithMatcher

// ...

        val index = 42 // index is 0 based, corresponds to row 43 from user's perspective

        onView(withId(R.id.myRecyclerView))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(43))
            .check(
                matches(
                    allOf(
                        childOfViewAtPositionWithMatcher(
                            R.id.myTextView1,
                            index,
                            withText("hello text 1 at line 43")
                        ),
                        childOfViewAtPositionWithMatcherMy(
                            R.id.myTextView2,
                            index,
                            withText("hello text 2 at line 43")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
```

Here are my build.gradle dependencies (newer versions may exist):

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0"
androidTestImplementation "it.xabaras.android.espresso:recyclerview-child-actions:1.0"
```

Comment: so index=43? and you should in that case make a change in the sample code?

Comment: I clarified the value of index.  It's actually 42 not 43 since index is 0-based.  Therefore it corresponds to row 43 from the user's perspective (where I'm assuming a user counts rows from 1 not 0).

Answer (score 2):

I have written a function that can check every view of view holder in recyclerview. Here is my function :

**recyclerViewId** is your recyclerview id

**position** is the position of your recyclerview

**itemMatcher** is your matcher function

**subViewId** is the id of recyclerview sub view (view of viewHolder)

```
    public static void checkRecyclerSubViews(int recyclerViewId, int position, Matcher<View> itemMatcher, int subViewId)
{
    onView(withId(recyclerViewId)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(position))
                                  .check(matches(atPositionOnView(position, itemMatcher, subViewId)));
}


    public static Matcher<View> atPositionOnView(
        final int position, final Matcher<View> itemMatcher, @NonNull final int targetViewId)
{

    return new BoundedMatcher<View, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView.class)
    {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description)
        {
            description.appendText("has view id " + itemMatcher + " at position " + position);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(final RecyclerView recyclerView)
        {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
            View targetView = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(targetViewId);
            return itemMatcher.matches(targetView);
        }
    };
}
```

And this is the examaple of using :

```
checkRecyclerSubViews(R.id.recycler_view, 5, withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE), R.id.text_view_plan_tittle);

checkRecyclerSubViews(R.id.recycler_view, 5, withText("test"), R.id.text_view_delete);
```

Answer (score 1):

For testing all items (include off-screen) use code bellow

Sample:

```
fun checkThatRedDotIsGone(itemPosition: Int) {
    onView(
            withId(R.id.recycler_view)).
            check(itemViewMatches(itemPosition, R.id.inside_item_view,
                    withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.GONE)))
}
```

Class:

```
object RecyclerViewAssertions {

fun itemViewMatches(position: Int, viewMatcher: Matcher<View>): ViewAssertion {
    return itemViewMatches(position, -1, viewMatcher)
}

/**
 * Provides a RecyclerView assertion based on a view matcher. This allows you to
 * validate whether a RecyclerView contains a row in memory without scrolling the list.
 *
 * @param viewMatcher - an Espresso ViewMatcher for a descendant of any row in the recycler.
 * @return an Espresso ViewAssertion to check against a RecyclerView.
 */
fun itemViewMatches(position: Int, @IdRes resId: Int, viewMatcher: Matcher<View>): ViewAssertion {
    assertNotNull(viewMatcher)

    return ViewAssertion { view, noViewException ->
        if (noViewException != null) {
            throw noViewException
        }

        assertTrue("View is RecyclerView", view is RecyclerView)

        val recyclerView = view as RecyclerView
        val adapter = recyclerView.adapter
        val itemType = adapter!!.getItemViewType(position)
        val viewHolder = adapter.createViewHolder(recyclerView, itemType)
        adapter.bindViewHolder(viewHolder, position)

        val targetView = if (resId == -1) {
            viewHolder.itemView
        } else {
            viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(resId)
        }

        if (viewMatcher.matches(targetView)) {
            return@ViewAssertion  // Found a matching view
        }

        fail("No match found")
    }
}
```

}

Solution based of this article > [Better Android RecyclerView Testing!](https://medium.com/koala-tea-assurance/better-android-recyclerview-testing-a5e3ed7ef38b)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using **kotlin** with proper "not found" descriptions and it should apply to most usecases:

If you only want to check that something exists within the entry at the given index, you can match using `withPositionInRecyclerView` with **position** and **recyclerview id** to find the row and use `hasDescendant(...)` combined with whatever matcher you like:

```kotlin
onView(withPositionInRecyclerView(positionToLookAt, R.id.my_recycler_view))
  .check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("text that should be somewhere at given position"))))
```

Please note that you might have to scroll on the recyclerView using `actionOnItemAtPosition` first so that the item is displayed.

If you want to be more precise and make sure that a specific view within the entry at the given index matches, just **add the view id** as a third parameter:

```kotlin
onView(withPositionInRecyclerView(positionToLookAt, R.id.my_recycler_view, R.id.my_view))
  .check(matches(withText("text that should be in view with id R.id.my_view at given position")))
```

So here is the helper method you will need to include somewhere in your test code:

```kotlin
fun withPositionInRecyclerView(position: Int, recyclerViewId: Int, childViewId: Int = -1): Matcher<View> =
    object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        private var resources: Resources? = null
        private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
        override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
            description?.appendText("with position $position in recyclerView")
            if (resources != null) {
                try {
                    description?.appendText(" ${resources?.getResourceName(recyclerViewId)}")
                } catch (exception: Resources.NotFoundException) {
                    description?.appendText(" (with id $recyclerViewId not found)")
                }
            }
            if (childViewId != -1) {
                description?.appendText(" with child view ")
                try {
                    description?.appendText(" ${resources?.getResourceName(childViewId)}")
                } catch (exception: Resources.NotFoundException) {
                    description?.appendText(" (with id $childViewId not found)")
                }
            }
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(view: View?): Boolean {
            if (view == null) return false
            if (resources == null) {
                resources = view.resources;
            }
            if (recyclerView == null) {
                recyclerView = view.rootView.findViewById(recyclerViewId)
            }
            return if (childViewId != -1) {
                view == recyclerView?.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)?.itemView?.findViewById(childViewId)
            } else {
                view == recyclerView?.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)?.itemView;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take in Kotlin, based on some [already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70008599) [published](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64241245) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31475962). Objectives:

- Helpful error message in case `RecyclerView` or target view can't be found (e.g. no `NullPointerException` if position is out-of-bounds)
- Helpful error message in case target view does not match expectations (all solutions starting with `onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))` just print details about `RecyclerView` itself in this case)
- Checks item at exact position, not just [any visible child that matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67878052)
- Can be used to match either item's root view or its specific descendant
- Can be used to perform actions on matched view
- Tests real view displayed on the screen, not [artificially created one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57852329)
- Avoids unnecessary work
- Minimal boilerplate, concise, but readable

Unfortunately, `Matcher` can't scroll `RecyclerView` automatically (`matchesSafely` runs on UI thread and can't wait until it's idle), so it should be done separately. Usage:

```kt
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
    .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(42))
onRecyclerViewItem(R.id.recycler_view, 42)
    .check(matches(isAssignableFrom(ConstraintLayout::class.java)))
onRecyclerViewItem(R.id.recycler_view, 42, R.id.text)
    .check(matches(withText("Item 42")))
onRecyclerViewItem(R.id.recycler_view, 42, R.id.button).perform(click())
```

Code:

```kt
fun onRecyclerViewItem(
    recyclerViewId: Int,
    position: Int,
    targetViewId: Int? = null
): ViewInteraction = onView(object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

    private lateinit var resources: Resources
    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder? = null
    private var targetView: View? = null

    override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
        fun Int.name(): String = try {
            "R.id.${resources.getResourceEntryName(this)}"
        } catch (e: Resources.NotFoundException) {
            "unknown id $this"
        }

        val text = when {
            recyclerView == null -> "RecyclerView (${recyclerViewId.name()})"
            holder == null || targetViewId == null -> "in RecyclerView (${recyclerViewId.name()}) at position $position"
            else -> "in RecyclerView (${recyclerViewId.name()}) at position $position and with ${targetViewId.name()}"
        }
        description.appendText(text)
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(view: View): Boolean {
        // matchesSafely will be called for each view in the hierarchy (until found),
        // it makes no sense to perform lookup over and over again
        if (!::resources.isInitialized) {
            resources = view.resources
            recyclerView = view.rootView.findViewById(recyclerViewId) ?: return false
            holder = recyclerView?.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position) ?: return false
            targetView = holder?.itemView?.let {
                if (targetViewId != null) it.findViewById(targetViewId) else it
            }
        }
        return view === targetView
    }
})
```

I've merged `onView` and matcher class directly into it, because I only use it this way, and `onRecyclerViewItem(...)` looks more readable then `onView(withPositionInRecyclerView(...))`. Matcher function and/or class can be extracted if you prefer so. The same code "in the wild", with imports, KDoc and my rewrite of `scrollToPosition` [can be found here](https://github.com/gmk57/mvvm-examples/blob/stateflow/example-kt-03adapters/src/androidTest/java/foo/bar/example/foreadapterskt/ui/EspressoTestMatchers.kt).

Answer (score 0):

Modified matcher solution for when you check if your item(Text in TextView) is first in RecyclerView.

```
// True if first item in the RV and input text
fun <T> customMatcherForFirstItem(name: String, matcher: Matcher<T>): Matcher<T> {
    return object: BaseMatcher<T> () {
        var isFirst = true
        override fun matches(item: Any): Boolean {
            if (isFirst && (item as TextView).text == name) {
                isFirst = false
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {}
    }
}
```

Usage: (returns true if child textview in the item has the same text as we expect/search)

```
    onView(withText("TEXT_VIEW_TEXT")).check(matches(
        customMatcherForFirstItem("TEXT_VIEW_TEXT", withParent(withId(R.id.recycler_view)))))
```

---

Based on -> https://proandroiddev.com/working-with-recycler-views-in-espresso-tests-6da21495182c