# How to check if text inside Recyclerview is displayed using Espresso

Tags: java, android, integration-testing, android-espresso

I am using Espresso to write some tests for a RecyclerView. Well, I am trying to verify that some texts in my recycler view items are correctly shown.

After some research, I could verify that the recycler item has or not an certain descendant:

```
    StatementInteractionRobot isExchangeHeaderCorrectlyShown(int position, Exchange exchange) {
            onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.transactions_cards)
                    .atPosition(position))
                    .check(matches(allOf(
                       hasDescendant(withText(exchange.getToCurrency().getSymbol())),

[some more checks here...]

            return this;
        }
```

But the problem is: I need to to verify that they are displayed or not (using isDisplayed()), but I am not really sure about how to do this, I trying some approaches but no luck so far.

So: **What do I need to change to verify that the view is displayed?**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I was able to fix this problem using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394569/how-to-assert-inside-a-recyclerview-in-espresso) solution.

Comment: Thanks @FaBioInsolia. It totally worked!