# Calling click on ViewHolder in Espresso test for RecyclerView does not call the Onclick listener of the view holder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, androidx-test

My fragment is as follows

```
public class NerdLauncherFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private final String TAG = this.getTag();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nerd_launcher, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.app_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        setAdapter();
        return view;
    }

    private void setAdapter() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        Collections.sort(resolveInfos, new Comparator<ResolveInfo>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ResolveInfo first, ResolveInfo second) {
                PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
                return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(
                    first.loadLabel(pm).toString(), second.loadLabel(pm).toString());
            }
        });
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ActivityAdapter(resolveInfos));
        Log.i(TAG, "Found : " + resolveInfos.size() + " activities.");
    }
}
```

My RecyclerView Adapter

```
public class ActivityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ActivityHolder> {

    private List<ResolveInfo> mResolveInfos;

    public ActivityAdapter(List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos) {
        mResolveInfos = resolveInfos;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ActivityHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        return new ActivityHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ActivityHolder holder, int position) {
        ResolveInfo resolveInfo = mResolveInfos.get(position);
        holder.bindView(resolveInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mResolveInfos.size();
    }
}
```

View Holder

```
public class ActivityHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        private TextView mTextView;

        private ImageView mImageView;

        private ResolveInfo mResolveInfo;

        public ActivityHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_app_name);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_app_image);
        }

        public void bindView(ResolveInfo resolveInfo) {
            mResolveInfo = resolveInfo;
            PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
            String appName = mResolveInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
            mImageView.setImageDrawable(mResolveInfo.loadIcon(pm));
            mTextView.setText(appName);
            mTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ActivityInfo activityInfo = mResolveInfo.activityInfo;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setClassName(
                activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, activityInfo.name).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Layout files: fragment_nerd_launcher.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/app_recycler_view">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

ViewAdapter Layout: simple_list_item_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_app_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/id_app_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The onclick method is not invoked by the espresso test.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ActivityInfo activityInfo = mResolveInfo.activityInfo;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setClassName(
            activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, activityInfo.name).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

When I run the app in Android Studio, then the onclick listener is invoked, but not when I write the espresso tests. My espresso tests are given below

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class NerdLauncherActivityTest {
  @Rule
  public ActivityScenarioRule<NerdLauncherActivity> activityScenarioRule =
      new ActivityScenarioRule<NerdLauncherActivity>(NerdLauncherActivity.class);

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    Intents.init();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    Intents.release();
  }


  @Test
  public void testLaunchApp() {
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.app_recycler_view)).perform(
        RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, ViewActions.click()));
    Matcher<Intent> expectedIntent = Matchers.allOf(IntentMatchers.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN),
        IntentMatchers.hasFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    Intents.intended(expectedIntent);
    Intents.intending(expectedIntent).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(0, null));
  }
}
```

It fails on this line

> Intents.intended(expectedIntent);

The stack trace

```
IntentMatcher: (has action: is "android.intent.action.SEND" and flags: 10000000)

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:[]
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1720)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:96)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:59)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:324)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:306)
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:190)
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:170)
at 
. . . . . 
. . . . . 
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2189)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Test RecyclerView ViewHolder Text with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678563/how-to-test-recyclerview-viewholder-text-with-espresso)

Comment: just remove this `IntentMatcher` because you'll not write tests while it crashes with an `AssertionFailedError`... or setup the expected `Intent` with an `ActivityRule`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I am using RecyclerViewMatcher's from espresso-contrib package.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I want to verify that the click was triggered. Click is not being triggered.

Comment: This test tests fails due to the wrong `Intent` and there is no `RecyclerViewMatcher` either.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I am testing for `ACTION_MAIN` intent. Can you tell me how I can do it correct?

Comment: I think you're clicking the whole `Recyclerview`, not any of the contained items. Just see the question/answer which I've flagged as a duplicate... the GIF shows what it does: it's clicking `Recyclerview` items. Migrating that to `androidx.test` should be simple, because it's just another name-space.

Comment: The assertion of the text is not a problem, but the click is not responding in Recyclerview.

Comment: The stack-trace says that the `Intent` is not matching.

Comment: That is because the the view holder click evnet is invoked the listener. I am setting the intent in the on click function

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this ? I am currently facing the same issue. An onClick listener inside a viewHolder is not being triggered.