# Test doesn't find text in recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have this test and I want to assert that a specific item is being loaded by retrofit and displyed in the recyclerview.

I already debugged and I know that the web request response is successful and returns the list of movies as expected.

```
 @Test
    fun findItem_checkItsText() {
        val result = tmdbApi.getMovies(AppConstants.LANGUAGE, 1).execute()

        if(result.isSuccessful) {
            val movieTitle = result.body()?.results?.get(0)?.title
            onView(withText(movieTitle)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        } else {
            AssertionFailedError()
        }


    }
```

The test fails with `androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "Hustlers"` message (`Hustlers` is the title of the movie at position `0`) and I don't know why. How can I check if data is loaded and displayed in recyclerview items?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assert inside a RecyclerView in Espresso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394569/how-to-assert-inside-a-recyclerview-in-espresso)

Comment: I suppose there is a ProgressBar while loading the info so that espresso will wait until the animations are stopped (the data is loaded)

Answer (score 0):

You can set Thread.sleep() between "val movieTitle" and "onView".
If this work, create Idling resource for your text. (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource)