# Android Espresso: Unable to detect the visible text in the espresso test

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

This is my use case.

1. Load a recycler view
2. Click on an item that will show a dialog with a radio group
3. Select a radio button (# 2) in my test
4. Click OK
5. Show the recycler view showing the updated text.

My unit test

```
@Test
public void onNonODeviceSwitchIsShown() throws Exception
{


onView(withText(getString(R.string.PushNotifications))).perform(click());
            onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem(hasDescendant(withText(R.string.general_notification_tone)),
                    click()));
            UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

        // Search for correct button in the dialog.
        UiObject toneText = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Adara"));
        toneText.click();
        UiObject2 okButton = uiDevice.findObjects(By.clazz(Button.class)).get(1);
        okButton.clickAndWait(Until.newWindow(), 5000);
        onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).check(
            ViewAssertions.matches(allOf(
                withText(R.string.custom))));

}
```

It fails with the following message, which means it does not detect any radio buttons:

> androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: '(with string from resource id: <2131887061>)' doesn't match the selected view.
>   Expected: (with string from resource id: <2131887061>)
>   Got: "RecyclerView{id=2131365043, res-name=recycler_view, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1584, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@bc6b8c6, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=9}"

This is the dialog which upon closing will show the recycler view.

[image: Dialog containing Radio Buttons]

This is the part of the recycler view after the dialog is closed.

[image: Recycler View]

This is the line that fails

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).check(
                    ViewAssertions.matches(allOf(
                        withText(R.string.custom))));
```

When I check the layout inspector, I see the following set up

```
RelativeLayout
  |
  | Ab (id/title) TextView - "General"
  | Ab (id/summary) TextView - "Custom"
```

I don't know why the assertions are failing even though the `Custom` text does exist in the recycler view.

Comment: This looks like a system dialog, have you tried this instead `UiObject mText = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("None"));`
`mText.click();`

Comment: This won't support localisation, will it?

Comment: No, this won't support localisation. However for RecyclerView you might need to give the cell position to target the assertions. Hope this answer helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31475962/1597616

Comment: That just validates that the id matches, but it does not recognise the click and does not invoke the ViewAction event.